# Passing arguments, parameters, swap function and a random number generator

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a random number generator that first swaps the minimum and maximum values and then swaps them again (back to their original state?). My other two questions are: how can I tell if the swap is actually taking place (because it appears to be an invisible process) and no matter which two values that are chosen as the minimum and maximum values the random number output is always 1.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int minimum;
int maximum;

//Swap function
void swap (int& minimum, int& maximum) {
    minimum = maximum;
    maximum = minimum;
}


int randomNumber;
//Random number generator
void randomNum() {
    minimum = minimum;
    maximum = maximum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    randomNumber = rand() % maximum + minimum;

    cout<<"Your random value is: " << randomNum;

}


int main() {

    cout<<"Please enter your minimum value: " << endl;
    cin>>minimum;

    cout<<"Please enter your maximum value: " << endl;
    cin>>maximum;

     swap (minimum, maximum); //Calling swap function
     randomNum(); //Needs to swap again somehow.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plethora of issues in your code:

- swapping can't take place if you don't save the value of `minimum` before overwriting it with `maximum`: the value is lost and on second assignment both just have same value (which is `maximum`)
- assigning a value to itself doesn't make any sense and I don't understand its purpose (eg `minimum = minimum`)
- operator precedence makes `rand() % maximum + minimum` parsed as `(rand() % maximum) + minimum` and that's not probably what you wanted
- if you want to generate a random number between an interval then you must use the difference between the bounds of the interval, not its sum, eg `rand() % (x - y)` to obtain a range `[x, y)`.
- calling `srand(time(NULL))` locally to `randomNum()` will reset the generator if you call the function multiple times in the same second
- I don't understand the whole purpose of swapping the values to swap them again, do you need to sort them so that the lesser is always stored in `minimum` or what?